# PHP Code for Hiding/Showing Content

Tags: php, date, time

I've always used the code below to show or hide banners starting from a certain date.

What I don't know is how to create a code to show a content from a certain day of the year to another day of the year.

**For example:** 
**I need to show up an image from 1 January to 31 July then hide it, and make it repeat every year.**

The code to show/hide from a certain date in Italian (dataoggi = datetime I think...):

```
<?php if ($dataoggi <= '20130701') { ?>

<div class="banner"> <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/image.jpg" width="460" height="400" /></a></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: So what is the problem with your code.. other than that it is not 2013 anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Charlotte Dunois's answer, or this:

```
<?php 
    $now=time(); 
    $year= (int)date("Y");
    if( $now>strtotime("1 January {$year}") && $now<strtotime("31 July {$year}") ){ ?>

<div class="banner"> <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/image.jpg" width="460" height="400" /></a></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Used:

- `time()` returns time integer for `>` and `<` comparison
- `(int)` converts a string to integer (not really necessary); this is called type casting
- `date()` returns specific parts from server BIOS time in given format; in our case "Y" is four-digit year
- `strtotime()` converts string date to number for `>` and `<` comparison

I hope this helps.

Comment: You forgot one strtotime() :)

Comment: Also the banner will disappear on the 31 july.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois true. :) fixed. And the 31st problem can be fixed in at least 2 ways so leaving it as it is.

Comment: Thank you @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL - Maybe I've figured out how to this even for one specific day. `<?php 
    $now=time(); 
    $year= (int)date("Y");
    if( $now=strtotime("25 December {$year}") ){ ?>  <div class="banner"> <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/image.jpg" width="460" height="400" /></a></div>

<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use mktime() to create a timestamp and then make a comparison with the current timestamp time().

```
$start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y'));
$end = mktime(23, 59, 59, 7, 31, date('Y'));
if($start <= time() AND $end >= time()) {
    //Show banner
}
```